# Is my bottle of "RooR"-brand glass cleaning liquid pure isopropyl alcohol or something else?

Tags: alcohols, cleaning, liquids

I have this exact bottle: https://www.grasscity.eu/media/catalog/product/cache/2b55fa971a29a7844993ad77b24950ac/i/m/img_3633_1_1.jpg

I originally purchased it to clean my vaporizer (I've since stopped doing that and thrown all the equipment away), and now I'm wondering if this liquid is "isopropyl alcohol", because I want to use it to clean video game cartridges' connectors/internals with cotton swabs.

The text is 100% in German, and does not mention "isopropyl" or "alcohol" anywhere. It has no ingredients listed anywhere. It's described as "biological glass cleaning". The store from which I bought it described it as "pure isopropyl alcohol", but who knows if they are lying/confused?

So, is this actually pure isopropyl alcohol? And can it thus safely be used for my cartridge/hardware cleaning purposes? Or is it some sort of weird proprietary mix which is only to be used for cleaning glass and causes horrible damage to anything else?

I'm surprised that they would not be legally required to have some sort of "list of ingredients". I thought that was definitely a law in Germany, like every other country I know of. And even if not a law, it seems reasonable to mention "isopropyl" or at least "alcohol" somewhere on the bottle. If it indeed is 100% pure isopropyl alcohol, you'd think they would want to brag about this and make a big deal of it.

It was very expensive.

Comment: It's impossible to tell from the image, why don't you edit your question to add the text ?

Comment: @porphyrin What do you mean? The text doesn't say anything useful beyond what I've already described. The "model number" thing doesn't yield any search results.

Comment: One thing that they can't (hopefully) skip is a clear sign showing flammability. If there is no warning about flammability then the product isn't just alcohol (in the sense that the alcohol conc is so low to compare with, say, vodka, and assuming the product is alcohol based). Perhaps there is not alcohol at all. Or there is just ethanol and much water. Avoid biological cleaners at least to replace alcohol because it is a relatively expensive non sense.